# Function won't update value into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, arraylist

I'm currently displaying an array into a SectionList in React Native, I'm trying to update in real-time the value `selected`, this is the array:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "data": Array [
      Object {
        "id": 1.01,
        "price": 1,
        "selected": false,
        "title": "Ranch",
        "type": "Sides",
      },
      Object {
        "id": 1.02,
        "price": 1,
        "selected": false,
        "title": "Blue Cheese",
        "type": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "required": false,
    "type": "Sides",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Array [
      Object {
        "id": 2.01,
        "price": 1,
        "selected": false,
        "title": "Hot Sauce",
        "type": "Sauces",
      },
      Object {
        "id": 2.02,
        "price": 1,
        "selected": false,
        "title": "Medium Sauce",
        "type": "Sauces",
      },
    ],
    "required": true,
    "type": "Sauces",
  },
]
```

this is the function I'm using to update the array:

```
const pressOptional = (e) => {    
      additional.map((item) => {
        if (item.type == e.type) {
          item.data.map((a => {
            if (a.id == e.id) {
              a.selected = !e.selected
            }
          }))
        }
      })
    }
```

I'm calling this function in a button displayed in the SectionList, and when I call it, I see it changing the value, but the SectionList still reads the previous data

Comment: Please create a state and then use the array as a state variable , your issue will be solved .

Comment: `() => this.setState({details: additional})` I'm trying to setState when I get the array, but it just returns an empty array

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return` the mapped value.

```
const pressOptional = (e) => {    
     return additional.map((item) => {
        if (item.type == e.type) {
          item.data.map((a => {
            if (a.id == e.id) {
              a.selected = !e.selected
            }
          }))
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Can, you, please, provide an example code in sandbox to make it easier to help you?